# Unit testing unavailable global function (couchapp, mocha)

Tags: node.js, couchdb, mocha.js

I'm trying to unit test a CouchDB design doc (written using [couchapp.js](https://github.com/mikeal/node.couchapp.js)), example:

```
var ddoc = {
  _id: '_design/example',
  views: {
    example: {
      map: function(doc) {
        emit(doc.owner.id, contact);
      }
    }
   }
}
module.exports = contacts
```

I can then require this file into a mocha test very easily.

The problem is CouchDB exposes a few global functions that the map functions use ("emit" function above) which are unavailable outside of CouchDB (i.e. in these unit tests).

I attempted to declare a global function in each test, for example:

```
var ddoc = require('../example.js')

describe('views', function() {
  describe('example', function() {
    it('should return the id and same doc', function() {
      var doc = {
        owner: {
          id: 'a123456789'
        }
      }

      // Globally-scoped mocks of unavailable couchdb 'emit' function
      emit = function(id, doc) {
        assert.equal(contact.owner.id, id);
        assert.equal(contact, doc);
      }
      ddoc.views.example.map(doc);
    })
  })
})
```

But Mocha fails with complaints of global leak.

All of this together started to "smells wrong", so wondering if there's better/simpler approach via any libraries, even outside of Mocha?

Basically I'd like to make mock implementations available per test which I can call asserts from.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I'd use sinon to stub and spy the tests. http://sinonjs.org/ and https://github.com/domenic/sinon-chai

Globals are well, undesirable but hard to eliminate. I'm doing some jQuery related testing right now and have to use `--globals window,document,navigator,jQuery,$` at the end of my mocha command line so... yeah.

You aren't testing CouchDb's emit, so you should stub it since a) you assume that it works and b) you know what it will return

```
global.emit = sinon.stub().returns(42);
// run your tests etc
// assert that the emit was called
```

This part of the sinon docs might be helpful:

```
it("makes a GET request for todo items", function () {
    sinon.stub(jQuery, "ajax");
    getTodos(42, sinon.spy());

    assert(jQuery.ajax.calledWithMatch({ url: "/todo/42/items" }));
});
```

Hope that helps.